# In supervised multiclass classification, why is the macro F1 score used instead of balanced accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

Let's say I have a 3-class problem and I want to build a classifier that can differentiate between the classes based on a set of features. I want to evaluate the model based on its ability to differentiate the 3 classes.

From my reading, it sounds like macro F1 score is the common metric used to evaluate classifiers on multiclass problems, where the F1 score is calculated for each class then the unweighted average of those F1 scores is used as the `macro F1 score`.

In other literature, I've seen the balanced accuracy used on multiclass problems, where the accuracy is calculated for each class then the unweighted average of those accuracies is used as the `balanced accuracy`.

Why would the macro F1 score be favored over balanced accuracy?

Isn't the balanced accuracy more interpretable, in the sense that a balance accuracy of < 0.5 tells us that the model performs worse than chance?

How do we interpret F1 score in the same way as balanced accuracy -- what threshold indicates that the classifier is doing better/worse than chance?

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

In multi-class classification class imbalance effects distort more easily the typical performance metrics. A couple of performance measures that are quite good for class imbalance are:

- Cohen's Kappa ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen's_kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa))
- The geometric mean (rather than the aritmetic mean) across classes

Both can be easily adapted to multi-class classification.

Answer (score 0):

On my opinion, F1 score is based on precision and recall, which can be suitable for more situations. For example, the negative samples are much less than the positive samples.

Comment: Balanced accuracy takes precision and recall into account as well. It is the average accuracy over all classes.